# How to add watch for dashed variable names in Google Chrome Debugger?

Tags: chromium, source-maps, javascript-debugger, livescript

How can we easily add dashed variable names (they are written in Livescript) into watch window in Chrome (Chromium) debugger? Right-click adds the variable as is, so it can not be recognized as a variable:

[image: dashed variable]

Comment: I believe you only need to camelCase the variable in the debugger: `stockOrdersPerLot`

Comment: yes, but how can I make it happen automatically?